# bind(0) function returns a used temporary port

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, port, bind

My udp server needs to generate a temporary unused port for each client, so I bind with zero-port to get it. But the bind function sometimes returns a used port, so client A received data which should have been sent to client B.

```
int _fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
if (_fd < 0)
{   
    return false;
}   

INT reuse = 1;
INT ret = setsockopt(_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(reuse));
if (ret == -1) 
{   
    return false;
}   

sockaddr_in local_addr;
int addr_len = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
local_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
local_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());
if (::bind(_fd, (sockaddr *) &local_addr, sizeof(local_addr)) == -1) 
{   
    return false;
}   

if (::getsockname(_fd, (sockaddr*)&local_addr, &addr_len) == -1) 
{   
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You do not set local_addr post to 0, do you?

Comment: no,I thought that 0 is the default value of sockaddr_in's port.

Comment: @WenJuanWu `struct` members don't have default values, and the fact that it is a `struct sockaddr_in` can't possibly change that. Set it to zero explicitly and re-test.

Comment: Thanks,I'll try it and tell you the result.

Comment: Yeah,it works,thank you very much!